# Is "in order to" correct to be used in a simple sentence?

Tags: sentence, present-tense

Can the clause "in order to" be used in a simple sentence?
I'm confused... Please let me know...

Comment: What is a 'simple sentence' according to you? We need more context **in order to** understand your question. We're confused. Please let us know.

Comment: We can judge better when you offer an example, since _to_ will almost always substitute perfectly for _in order to_.

Comment: I added this comment in order to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, *in order to* may be substituted with *to*. Anyhow, *In order to* is a rather formal expression and is not often to be found in general conversations.

Let me show you its proper usage based on a few examples:

- I went to my friend's house **in order** to study.
- She worked hard **in order to** pass her exam.
- We took the taxi **in order to** save time.

To answer your question, *in order to* may be used in a simple sentence, as instructed above. As you can see, *in order to* can be replaced with *to* in those examples demonstrated.

For further information, I'd strongly recommend you to check this out: 
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/in-order-to

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the sentence, but it can be used. As in: He took a book with him **in order to** have something to read on the train.